# How to indent a block in beamer?

Tags: beamer, indentation

I am creating a presentation using Beamer with the Hannover template. Here is one slide from the presentation:

```
  \begin{frame}
\frametitle{Vision(Image Acquisition \footnotesize contd.. \large)}
\begin{block}{Camera Calibration}
    \begin{itemize}
      \scriptsize\item All supported features are queried
      \scriptsize\item Sliders are created
    \end{itemize}
    \bigskip
    \begin{enumerate}
      \scriptsize\item Automatic driver-made adjustments are disabled
      \scriptsize\item Values taken from sliders are set
      \scriptsize\item Config file is updated
    \end{enumerate}
\end{block}
\bigskip
\begin{block}{Problems}
    \begin{itemize}
      \scriptsize\item Flickering
      \scriptsize\item JPEG Artefacts
    \end{itemize}
\end{block}
  \end{frame}
```

As you can see, there are two blocks. The first is the main one, and the second is more like additional remarks. I want the second block to be indented for this reason. How to I manage to do that?

Comment: From a presenters view it is better to put the problems block in another frame.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One idea could be use the `column` and `columns` environment. For example, look at this MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Vision(Image Acquisition \footnotesize contd.. \large)}
\begin{block}{Camera Calibration}
    \begin{itemize}
      \scriptsize\item All supported features are queried
      \scriptsize\item Sliders are created
    \end{itemize}
    \bigskip
    \begin{enumerate}
      \scriptsize\item Automatic driver-made adjustments are disabled
      \scriptsize\item Values taken from sliders are set
      \scriptsize\item Config file is updated
    \end{enumerate}
\end{block}
\bigskip
%% Second block indented
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{0.1\textwidth}

\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.9\textwidth}
\begin{block}{Problems}
    \begin{itemize}
      \scriptsize\item Flickering
      \scriptsize\item JPEG Artefacts
    \end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In this way you decide the lenght of the indentation choosing the lenght of the two columns. It is important that the first one is empty, to shift the block. The graphical result is:

[image]